# Best place to read about the algorithms and protocols underlying bitcoin?

Tags: specification

I haven't been able to find a whitepaper or technical spec detailing the bitcoin algorithms and protocols. Google is flooded with too much hand-wavy nonsense. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this awesome article that answered all my questions:

[How the Bitcoin Protocol Actually Works](http://www.michaelnielsen.org/ddi/how-the-bitcoin-protocol-actually-works/)

Answer (score 2):

[Bitcoin: A Peer-to-Peer Electronic Cash System](http://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf)

by: Satoshi Nakamoto

That would be a good place to start.

Comment: Google has become so convenient, sometimes I forget to go to the source :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The cryptographic primitives used in Bitcoin are SHA-256 and ECDSA.

For ECDSA: http://www.secg.org/collateral/sec2_final.pdf

For SHA-256: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-4/fips-180-4.pdf